# Using end() inside loop returns null but arrays print correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have the below code inside a while loop, it gets a json array from a custom field in WordPress, turns it into a php array which prints correctly. I see each array printed in the AJAX response.

If each array is printing correctly that means `$testmeta` is storing an array each loop, why is `$position = end($testmeta);` returning this error `Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

```
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {

    $results_array = get_post_meta($thepostid, 'results',true);
    $testmeta = json_decode($results_array,true);
    print_r($testmeta);
    $position = end($testmeta);
    }
}
```

I've tried placing `unset($testmeta)` below the code and it didn't help.

I also tried `print_r(end($testmeta));` which prints the end of each array but still throws the error

Comment: Can you post more code? The whole loop would be useful.

Comment: @JimD see my update I tried printing another way and it works but still getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe that $testmeta is empty (sometimes round the loop), so test for it before assigning:

```
if (!empty($testmeta)) $position = end($testmeta);
```

Comment: That's it, I forgot not all fields have json arrays so nulls are getting into the loop. Thanks!

Comment: if its empty, `end()` will return false and not produce a warning. Warning appears, if the array is null.